# How to make cross site collection call using CSOM for on premise provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, csom

I have requirement that Provider hosted app is in
in http://localhost:1234/site1 for example

and I need to get the list items from the list in http://localhost:1234/site2

```
Uri hostWeb = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

using (var clientContext =  TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
{
    List list =                     clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListofSiteCollection2");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
    clientContext.Load(item);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried? What's the issue here? You don't know how? Is it not working? We need more info.

Comment: I gave 'web', 'site collection' level permission to that app

Comment: It is not working I deployed app to one site collection, I specifing list of another site collection to get the data. It is saying "List is unknown"

Comment: any information required

Comment: Put your code in your question.

Comment: can u check now

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to read the list from the host web, not from the other site collection.  You need to create another `ClientContext` for the other site collection, and use it to get the list object.

```
var site2Ctx = new ClientContext("http://localsite:1234/site2");
try 
{
    var list = site2Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list display name");
    // do whatever you need to do
} finally 
{
    site2Ctx.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I need create one more client context to get the host web list right ?

Comment: Yes, your current code will work for the list on the host web.